# How to parse json with java language keywords

Tags: java, json, gson

Is there away to parse json with java keywords like class, case, default etc. to java object using Gson library?
The lines

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject myObject = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

simply parse json to my pojo, but I have key "class" in my json and I can't use the field "class" in java classes.

Comment: Certainly, you can parse JSON into regular Maps and Lists, and any keyname will be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, annotate your fields with `@SerializedName`, specifying the name of the field.

```
@SerializedName("class")
private String classField;
```

Or use a custom `TypeAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use annotations. These annotations tell Gson which JSON field maps to which Java property:

http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/